# Is it possible to print anything over foil-print?

Tags: print-design, print-production, packaging, overprint

Is it possible to print anything over the foil print or would you need to mask the foil and fill in the colours? 
For example - this packaging design: https://www.prettylittlething.com/isle-of-paradise-over-it-magic-self-tan-eraser.html
[image: example]

Do you think they just detailed the foil all around the letters or were they able to print over it? If there is a possibility, would it have to be some special colour?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly but for me this is a question more about the printing technique than the design itself. Maybe it's worth trying to ask this questions on some printing forum. There you would definitely get an answer to your question.

Comment: In the image you are posting I believe that I can see a thin white outline on the black parts, which indicates that black doesn't overprint - it knocks-out the foil, and it even has tiny "buffer" (to account for misalignment) in form of a white stroke around all the black parts. I don't know if it's possible to print on top of foil (I believe not), but depending on your design you might be able to just print the colored letters with an added stroke and then have negative letters in the foil on top? If I were you I would talk to the print shop about this..

Comment: Always ask your vendor what they require before making assumptions. There is no need to make life more complicated in anticipation of an issue that probably doesn't exist. Chances are, even if it were a problem, the vendor can suggest a better solution, especially if this is your first time preparing files for this type of project. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is absolutely normal to print over foilstamp. Moreover: print over the foilstamp is also much easier than to print to match precisely position on the knockouted foil. So don't worry, just prepare files correctly. Most likely printer will want to have foil and print parts as a separate files.

Answer (score 3):

Always best to discuss your options with your printer.

1. Printing on foil is common, but then usually a cold foil technique is used. Hotstamp foils create too much relief for a good ink transfer.
2. Often, the printer has the foil unit installed at the end of the press (after the printing stations). In that case, a design like this would require a 2nd print run, adding cost.
3. An alternative is to use a foil coated substrate and print an opaque white backing. But tricky to get a good coverage with all that white in the design.

Answer (score 0):

you can make design where 2 different printers are used, the foil part is laserjet black that later is laminated with foil and black letters are inkjet, so you print the design by using 2 printers same page each prints different part, then run the design trough foiling and foil will only gets added to the laserjet part.